# React Native - IOS device screens zoom in issue in standard mode

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native, splash-screen

- In my React-Native app, I have shown `splash screen` from react-native and not (**Android/IOS**) natively.
- But when splash screen loads it zooms in automatically and the same behavior is for other screens.
- It works well in **Android** but not in **IOS**.
- From Xcode(10.1) I have removed `LaunchScreen.xib` as my splash screen requires some `api` calls.

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMkWW.jpg) [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAKw2.jpg)

Comment: Can you please post you splash screen code ?

Comment: I think the issue exists IOS devices nothing wrong with the code!